# What type is join is required for the desired result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in mySQL:

First table:

```
(TABLE1)
Fruit + Shipn_Code +  Asmble_ID 
Apple |   .22      |    931   
Orange|   .22      |    931
Grape |   .22      |    931
Pear  |   .64      |    621
```

Second table:

```
(TABLE2)
Fruit +  Moved_By  +    My_Date
Apple |   110      |    2/17
Apple |   115      |    2/17
Apple |   119      |    3/1
Orange|   110      |    3/5
Grape |   120      |    3/7
```

The desired result is as follows

```
(Desired Result from query)
Fruit +  110  +  115 +  119
Apple |   1   |   1  |   1
Orange|   1   |   0  |   0
Grape |   0   |   0  |   0
```

I am not sure how to query mySQL5.6 for the desired result.

Comment: did you try any queries? It seems you just need data from the second table.

Comment: How is the result related to the input tables? ]

Comment: Why isn't Pear in the result? And why isn't there a 120 column?

Comment: It looks like you'll need a `LEFT JOIN` and pivot.

Comment: There is no Pear in the results because it does not have a .22 Ship_code. This is part of the reason why this is hard to figure out.

Comment: It sounds like you need more clarity in your question before we can help you. Also, what queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to convert Table2 first two column data to Row based Matrix. You cannot do this using a single mysql query you may have to do this programmatically through a small script.